# Linq statements, multiple where clauses

Tags: linq

I have this linq statement I just wrote:

```
Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name).Where(l => l.type == "SERV").FirstOrDefault();
```

I am wondering if this is how you do `select from where and ...` or if there is a better way to do this

I am trying to do select from locations name where the name is the name passed in and the type is the type passed in, get me the first location that matches this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to chain `Where`s - you can use `&&` instead. Moreover, since `FirstOrDefault` takes a condition, you can move the entire clause inside the call, like this:

```
Location loc = db
    .Locations
    .FirstOrDefault(l => l.name == name && l.type == "SERV");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will work just fine, but you can also just do this:

```
Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == "SERV").FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE:**

Since this is apparently going against a database object I was curious what the underlying SQL would look like in each case - my guess is they would be the same.

I used a ToTraceString() extension to view the SQL and just as expected, they are the same.